# What does the this javascript regular expression do?: "var match = self.location.href.replace(/\/$/i, '');"

Tags: javascript, regex

I saw this expression in another codebases library as part of the following sequence:

```
var url = sel.anchorNode.parentNode.href;
var match = self.location.href.replace(/\/$/i, '');
var replaced = url.replace(match,'');
```

It was suggest that the regular expression might strip of the trailing path to just reutrn the base URL but I created a fiddle to test that theory and it doesn't seem to check out.

http://jsfiddle.net/funkyeah/WEQZZ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only strips the trailing slash. A single slash `/`

Comment: so what do those 3 lines of code effectively do?? 1. It gets the value of an href attribute, 2. it gets the current URL with a trailing slash stripped off if it has one, 3. It effectively removes the current URL from the href value of the selected node?!? ... The code is from a WYSIWYG editor for the insert link functionality so it doesn't really make sense unless I am reading it wrong.

Comment: Sorry a typo it is a slash not backslash. It gets rid of trailing slash so it can add some parameters to the URL(according to my assumption, but really not necessary, ? and /? Both works)

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression strips a trailing slash (if any), but that in combination with the last line (`replaced = ...`) gets the URL of the link with the URL of the current page (with the trailing slash, if any, removed) removed from it.